Question on 1D Scattering Resonances
I'm reading Henley and Garcia's Subatomic Physics.  To introduce the concept of resonances they use a 1D square well scattering example.  Resonances are where the transmission coefficient goes to one.
But in data examples, resonances are defined by the cross section becoming large.
So these two things seem contradictory to me. If the transmission coefficient is one, then the particles move past the scattering center in a straight line.  But a high cross section, means there is a lot of interaction between the particle beam and the scattering center. Particles are scattered.
Can someone clear up my confusion?

good question. What does the energy spectrum look like vs. the depth and width of the  well?

How can they move in straight line if 1. There are forces acting on them. 2. Wrong to consider them as particles they are waves spread out over a certain distance.

Resonances in general are associated with quasi-bound (metastable) states of the scattering potential. When the energy of the falling wave is close to the energy of the metastable state, the scattering amplitude exhibits some special behavior due to interaction with the metastable state. However, this "special behavior" may lead both to a peak or a drop in the scattering amplitude depending on interaction details. So you are right, the 1D example and 3D scattering examples which you mentioned demonstrated different behavior, but the common feature is the presence of the metastable state.
The interaction details which may lead to different scattering amplitude features at resonance are as follows. It is known that near the energy of the metastable state with the enegy $E$ and lifetime $\Gamma$, the scattering amplitude $a(\epsilon)$ has a pole at $E - i\Gamma/2$ as a function of the incident wave energy $\epsilon$ . Therefore, we can write it as
$$
a(\epsilon) = \frac{\alpha}{\epsilon - E + \frac{i\Gamma}{2}} + \beta + O(\epsilon - E + i\Gamma/2),
$$
where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are some complex numbers. The scattering cross-section is proportional to $|a(\epsilon)|^2$.
The resulting dependencies of the cross-section on energy are called Fano resonances. Depending on the relative phase between $\alpha$ and $\beta$, the cross-section may exhibit a minimum, a maximum, or both. This happens due to interference between two terms in the expansion of $a(\epsilon)$, and this interference can be either constructive or destructive.
I think that in many cases it is possible to neglect the parameter $\beta$. In this case, the resonance takes the form of a usual Lorentz peak.

In the theory of scattering one defines phase shift $\delta$ as the change in phase of the outgoing to incoming wave. At those particular points where a resonance occurs this quantity is $\pi$/2. The scattering crossection on the otherhand is proportional to modulus square of (exp(i2$\delta$)-1). Hence at a resonance the scattering crosssection is high. The transmission coefficients T are related to phase shifts. They are given by 1-|exp(i2$\delta$)|$^2$. So for the T to be 1 the phase shift has to be imaginary. The absorption crossection which measures the removal of incident flux is however proportional to T.
In fact when the phase shift is $\pi$/2 the incident wave can penetrate the various barriers and the probability of finding it inside the potential is very high. So it comes down to how the transsmission coefficient is defined.
Paper Phys Rev C Vol 1 No. 3 March 1970 page 864 by George Michaud et  al, talks about square well and also another one Review of Modern Physics vol 34 No.4 Oct 62 page 723 by Enrich Vogt
